# CaptureSource.Start() throws System.UnauthorizedAccessException in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I have problem with using camera in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 application. I want just to initialize camera and see its preview (for now I don't need any photos or video capture). I have found [nice and simple example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394041%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and

```
private CaptureSource captureSource;
private VideoCaptureDevice videoCaptureDevice;

private void InitializeVideoRecorder()
{
    try
    {
        if (captureSource == null)
        {
            captureSource = new CaptureSource();
            var a = captureSource.VideoCaptureDevice;

            videoCaptureDevice = CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetDefaultVideoCaptureDevice();

            captureSource.CaptureFailed += OnCaptureFailed;

            if (videoCaptureDevice != null)
            {
                VideoRecorderBrush = new VideoBrush();
                VideoRecorderBrush.SetSource(captureSource);

                captureSource.Start();
                CameraStatus = "Tap record to start recording...";
            }
            else
            {
                CameraStatus = "A camera is not supported on this phone.";
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        CameraStatus = "ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

The code stops at `captureSource.Start();` throwing `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.`.

First of all I found information (on the same page) that `ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA` capability is needed in `WMAppManifest.xml'. But I have problem with adding it, because:

1. I can't find this capability in designer
   [image: Designer capabilities]
2. I get error when I add it manualy to .xml file
   [image: WMAppManifest.xml capabilities]

Error reproduced below:

```
Warning 1   The 'Name' attribute is invalid - The value 'ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest:ST_Capabilities' - The Enumeration constraint failed.
Error   3   App manifest validation failed. Value 'ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA' of attribute '/Package/Capabilities/Capability/@Name' must be a valid capability.
```

I have even found the same solution on SO [WP8.1 SilverLight Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera Access Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267173/wp8-1-silverlight-microsoft-devices-photocamera-access-denied)

**Can somebody tell me why can't I use original MSDN solution to this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it looks like you're trying to add that capability to `Package.appxmanifest` instead of `WMAppManifest.xml`. You should be able to find `WMAppManifest.xml` under Solution Explorer -> <your project> -> Properties:

[image]

Opening that file should give you the option to add `ID_CAP_*` capabilities.

Second, you need to specify *both* `ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA` and `ID_CAP_MICROPHONE` in order to use `CaptureSource.Start()`, even if you're only using one of the devices.

Comment: Thanks for great answer. I didn't search in properties, I was sure that Package.appxmanifest is the right file (the names are very similar). I found both `ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA` and `ID_CAP_MICROPHONE` in proper `WMAppManifest.xml` file and now it works perfectly :)